# OOP MySQLi Connect

Tags: php, oop

Im newbie in OOP. I have class Database

```
class Database{
private $host;
private $user;
private $pass;
private $db;
public $mysqli;

function db_connect(){
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->pass = '';
    $this->db = 'db';

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
    return $this->mysqli;
}
```

Inside class Database i have function db_num

```
function db_num($sql){
    $num = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($this->mysqli,"{$sql}"));
    return $num;
}
```

But it cant connect to database when im using in con argument $this->mysqli

Comment: this may help you http://codingbin.com/mysqli-database-connection-with-oops/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is bad practice to mix mysqli object style and procedural style.

Try this:

```
function db_num($sql){
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
    return $result->num_rows;
}
```

Be sure to connect to the database before you call `db_num()`, e.g.:

```
$db = new Database();
$db->db_connect();
$db->db_num("SELECT fields FROM YourTable");
```

A cleaner way in my opinion would be to call `db_connect` inside the constructor:

```
class Database{
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $db;
  public $mysqli;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db_connect();
  }

  private function db_connect(){
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->pass = '';
    $this->db = 'db';

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
    return $this->mysqli;
  }

  public function db_num($sql){
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        return $result->num_rows;
  }
}

$db = new Database();
$db->db_num("SELECT fields FROM YourTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/** 
 * Creating a class for the database connection
 * To start using the database connection like this: $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
*/

class DatabaseFactory {
    protected $servername = "servername";
    protected $username = "root";
    protected $password = "root";
    protected $dbname = "databasename";
    private static $factory;
    private $database;

    public static function getFactory() {
        if(!self::$factory) {
            self::$factory = new DatabaseFactory();
        }
        return self::$factory;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        if(!$this->database) {
            try {
                $this->database = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
            } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo "Error:" .$error;
                exit;
            }
        }
        return $this->database;
    }
}
```

Comment: for closing the database = $database -> close();
echo("<script>location.href = '?p=url check session';</script>");