# Can't get query to work in php CRUD system for checking duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I have a CRUD system and have created validation for three of the fields to make sure they are not empty which works perfectly. I would like to add further validation by making sure the ID does not already exist.

Here is the code..

```html
$required = array('id', 'name', 'family');

$noDouble = true;

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}else{echo "connected";}

$query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=='" . $product->id ."'");




if (!$query1){
 $noDouble = false;
 
}

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
 if (empty($_POST[$field])){
  $error = true;
 }
}




if($_POST && $error) {
 
 echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>All fields required</div>";
 
}elseif($_POST && $noDouble) {
 
 echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>That part number already exists</div>";
 
}

// if the form was submitted 
elseif ($_POST){
 
    // set product property values
 $product->id = $_POST['id'];
    $product->name = $_POST['name'];
 $product->family = $_POST['family'];
    //$product->number = $_POST['number'];
 $product->description = $_POST['description'];
    $product->ext_description = $_POST['ext_description'];
 $product->PRF = $_POST['PRF'];
 
 if(isset($_POST['publish'])){
    //$stok is checked and value = 1
    $published = $_POST['publish'];
 $product->publish = $_POST['publish'];
 }
 else{
  //$publish is not checked and value=0
  $published = 0;
  $product->publish = 0;
 }
 //$product->publish = $_POST['publish'];
/*  $product->category_id = $_POST['category_id'];  */
 
    // create the product
    if($product->create()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Product was created.</div>";
    }
 
 
}
```

However, it doesn't seem the if statement for the query is working as it continues to tell me the part number exists. Is there something wrong with my query? I've also tried replacing `$product->id` with `$_POST['id']` but that causes more errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's nothing wrong with the query itself per say. Your logic, however, is problematic in two ways.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=='" . $product->id ."'";
```

1. This is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is bad and you need to fix that. Such a vulnerability is not only dangerous to your application's security, but possibly your entire system. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` to bind your parameters.
2. You're not actually doing anything with the query you wrote. To actually query it you'll need to execute it.
3. There should only be one equal sign after `id`.

At this point, I suggest you take a look at a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). Completely fixing your code is a little outside the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to execute the query, I just want to make it false (0) instead of true if the product id doesn't exists. Is there something else you would suggest?

ps. been through many PDO tutorials but thought this would be an easy fix. Not worried about injections as this is a local application. Thanks for you time!

Comment: You need to *execute* the query (aka submit it to the database) to get a result. All you've done is create a string. You have not touched the database, and have therefore not gotten a result.

Comment: As a side note if the id column is a numerical value it doesn't need to be encased in quotes. That's just a waste of effort no the part of the original code.

Comment: While @Jacobm001 is entirely correct, I would like to suggest a shorthand solution to the significant security hole here with: `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =  ". (int)$product->id ` . Note the single `=` and the lack of quote marks and the forcing of the value to an `integer`

Comment: @DesignStuff You can't use OOP and Procedural MySQLi on the same connection. [one of many references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321795/oop-mysqli-connect)

Comment: @Jacobm001 Sorry about that. Thank god its only local! I don't know why this seems so hard to figure out.

Comment: @DesignStuff: your code still isn't checking the results. It's merely checking for the existence of a variable, really.

Comment: Doesn't `if (!$query1)` check if the query is false?

Comment: @DesignStuff: Nope, `mysqli_query()` only returns `false` if the query fails. That's usually due to a bad query, not an empty result set.

Comment: So should I check with a query that should be true first? I didn't even think I'd have to use another DB connection since I've already done it, but this is the only other thing I can think of doing.

Comment: @DesignStuff: you need to actually read the results of the query. At this point, you're well outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I definitely am. I can't even get the query to give me a true result even with a true query.

Comment: @DesignStuff. At this point I would recommend that you ask a new question focusing on how to read the query results.

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work here what I added 
`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

$id = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '');

$query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$id}'");



if ((mysqli_num_rows($query1)==0)){
 $noDouble = false;
 
}else{
 $noDouble = "true";
}

`
Its working perfect right now.. hopefully it keeps working :)

Comment: @DesignStuff: I'm glad you got it working. If this answer helped, please upvote or accept the answer as helpful. :)

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help.